# DateBounds gives strange results

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

**This has been fixed in v13.0.1**

---

In v12.3.1, this code

```
DateBounds[
 {DateObject[{2013, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.]}, 
 "Year"]
```

gives

[image]

which seems wrong.

Can this be considered as a bug?

And just out of curiosity, what's the possible cause for such result?

---

**update 20210901**

After several trials, it seems the granularity in `DateObject` has something to do with the seeming bug.

- with `Instant`:

`DateBounds[{DateObject[{2013, 12, 31, 1, 0}, "Instant"]}, "Year"]` gives
[image]

- without `Instant`:

`DateBounds[{DateObject[{2013, 12, 31, 1, 0}]}, "Year"]` gives
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looked into the definition code of `DateBounds` using `ResourceFunction["PrintDefinitions"][DateBounds]` and found this should be due to a bug in handling `DateObject`s with granularity of `Instant`:

1. for `DateBounds` with `gran` specified, the ending bound is further processed by `getFinalGranularInstance`:

```
System`DateUtilitiesDump`iDateBounds[Pattern[DateUtilitiesDump`a, 
Blank[]], Pattern[DateUtilitiesDump`gran, 
Blank[String]] ? DateAndTime`CalendarGranularityQ] := With[
    {res = System`DateUtilitiesDump`iDateBounds @ a},
    If[And[ListQ[res], SameQ[Length @ res, 2]],
            {
                DateObject[First @ res, gran],
                System`DateUtilitiesDump`getFinalGranularInstance[Last @ res, 
      gran]
            },
            res
        ]
   ];
```

2. in `getFinalGranularInstance`, apparently the ending `date` is unnecessarily cast into a `DateObject` in `gran` (`Year` in my case):

```
System`DateUtilitiesDump`getFinalGranularInstance[
   date : DateObject[_, "Instant", __], Pattern[
   DateUtilitiesDump`gran, 
Blank[]]] := 
  DateObject[DateObject[date, gran] + -Quantity[1, "Seconds"], gran];
```

Filed a bug report to WRI (CASE:4856153).

Answer (score 0):

You need a *list* of times in order to get bounds:

```
DateBounds[
{DateObject[{2013, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, 
 "Instant", "Gregorian",1.]}]
```

[image]

If you want the *year* that bounds the specific instant you list,

```
DateBounds[{DateObject[{2013, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian",
    1., "Year"]}]
```

(v. 11.3)

Comment: Thanks for the correction: I missed that in the question and have now added it. However, the result was the same. I've added the version info (v12.3.1). Which version do you use?

Comment: also, your code *differs* from what is in the question: yours doesn't include the granularity `"Year"`.

Comment: thanks for your updates. however, `DateObject[{2013, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant","Gregorian", 1., "Year"]` seems not to be a documented usage? while in the documentation of [DateBounds—Wolfram Language Documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateBounds.html), `DateBounds[interval, gran]` is a valid usage.